# What can I do to earn money, with the fleet of Virtual Private Servers I own?

Tags: consulting, group-freelancing

I own a lot of servers, Virtual Private Servers in specific. Those resources are being wasted. How do I put them to good use to earn a substantial amount of money?

Please give me detailed ideas and suggestions.

P.S.: I'm a techie. To be more specific, a Python Developer, and a Linux Systems Admin.

Comment: Most VPS owners sell hosting.

Comment: Tell you the truth the outcome is endless owning lots of servers.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what are your specialties? You can rent out partitions of the Servers, you could host a series of game servers and get paid for ad revenue and donationware, you could start a web hosting application and have people pay in a month to month basis for you to host their websites. Honestly the possibilities are endless.